# creating a file

Tags: java

I want to create a file but the below code doesn't create any file.

```
package InputOutput;

import java.io.*;

public class FinalProject{

    private File f;

    public File createFile() throws IOException{
        f = new File("E:\\Programming\\Class files\\practice\\src\\InputOutput\\helpSystem.txt");
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        FinalProject fp = new FinalProject();
        fp.createFile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) represents a path name to a file or a directory, not a writable file stream. If you need to create a file, call `createNewFile` on the `File` object:

```
try {
    f.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // Cannot create new file
}
```

Comment: I tried your code for creating a file.
Is it supposed to be "fp.createFile().createNewFile();"?? or something like "fp.createNewFile()"?

Comment: @nick-s `createNewFile` is a method on `File`. Since your `createNewFile` method returns a `File`, you can call `createNewFile` on it. You could also use `f` variable that your `createFile()` method sets. Finally, you could add a call to `createNewFile()` right in your `createFile()` method.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 
I couldn't understand the use of createFile() method called by f variable. I tried using your code but there is compile error while if I just use 'f.createNewFile()' it works fine.
Can you tell me the purpose of using createFile() before createNewFile() in ur code?

Comment: @nick-s I wanted to keep modifications to your code to the minimum, so I suggested a change `fp.createFile();` to `fp.createFile().createNewFile();`. However, it does not matter from where you call `createNewFile()`: that was the only part missing from your code, which was otherwise correct.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in your createFile method:

```
if(!f.exists()) {
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: `createNewFile()` *"..creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and **only if a file with this name does not yet exist**."* (The `if` check is redundant.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct code to create the file.

```
public File createFile() throws IOException{
f = new File("E:\\Programming\\Class files\\practice\\src\\InputOutput\\helpSystem.txt");
if(!f.exists()) {
f.createNewFile();
}
return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the createNewFile method which creates a new file if the specified file not exists
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) is the link to the instructions.

Hope it helped!